# How to reference a variable of the parent object?

Tags: javascript

How do I reference the value of `gar` from within `bar` and within `foo` itself?

```
var foo = 
{
  gar : function() { },

  bar : 
  {
    field1 : gar // how do I reference gar here?
                 // should it be foo.gar?
                 // or just this.gar?
                 // or just gar?
                 // all of them are undefined
  }, 

  har : gar      // and what about here?
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of an object initializer you can instantiate an anonymous constructor:

```js
var foo = new function() {
  this.gar = function() { };
  this.bar = { field1: this.gar };
  this.har = this.gar;
};
```

Comment: Thank you. 5 mins before I mark it as the right answer.

Comment: No, wait. Inside of `bar`, `this.gar` evaluates to `undefined`.

Comment: Wouldn't the meaning of `this` change when inside the curlies of `bar`?

Comment: @WaterCoolerv2 `this` is function scoped. It does not change inside the object initializer.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do it directly, there is no explicit reference to the parent Object in JavaScript.
  Another option is to wrap your object behavior and attributes in a function, that way you can keep the closure and don't really need a constructor:

```
var foo = function(){
  var gar = function(){console.log('gar')};
  return {
    gar: gar,
    bar: {
      field1: gar
    }, 
    har: gar
  };
}();
```

**Update**

The example was going to have a problem in strict mode, read comments above about it:

```
var foo = function(){
  this.gar = function(){console.log('gar')};
  return {
    gar: this.gar,
    bar: {
      field1: this.gar
    }, 
    har: this.gar
  };
}();
```

Comment: Thank you. I understand what you said.

Comment: Note `this.gar` will throw in strict mode and create a global variable in non-strict mode. Better use a variable.

Comment: @Oriol you're right better change that in the example code

Comment: perfect although if you want to run the function, change to this:
  return {
    gar: gar()

Now console will print gar:

Comment: @Matho It seems you included the old code to acknowledge I corrected that issue. That's not necessary, posting only the fixed code is ok.

Answer (score 0):

You can extend the object after initial creation;

```
var foo = {
  gar: function() { },
  bar: { }
}

foo.bar.field1 = foo.gar;
foo.har = foo.gar;
```